# remove a file from a jar using shell

Tags: shell

I want to remove a file from a jar. However this file should only be removed from a specific folder. I am using below command but no luck

```
zip -d abc.jar /myfolder/test1.txt
```

Kindly suggest

Comment: If you use `zip -l` to list contents, is the leading `/` there? If not, does taking it out fix things?

Comment: BTW, questions that are just as applicable to interactive command line use as to scripting are generally better suited to our sister site [UNIX.se]

Comment: If you need a version of `abc.jar` lacking a certain file, it seems like it would be better to build a jar file without the file in the first place.